# Why is Advantage/Fox e.g. car rental half the price of the market leaders?

Tags: car-rentals

I just arranged a rental car pick-up at MCO for this weekend. In order to get the Hotwire "hot rate" you need to wait until after you book to see what the company is. I have typically been lucky in getting those rates from the market leaders e.g. Budget, Hertz. But this time I got Advantage. The price was almost half of the market leaders.

Why is this? Is the service experience rated poorly, hence the low prices? Is it because of a lack of advertising?

Comment: There is no way of knowing for certain why a company has priced a product or service a particular way, as such things are closely held proprietary secrets that their competitors would quickly undermine if made public. One may assume that they need to make up for having a smaller fleet, fewer locations, less extensive partnerships, more downmarket image, and so on compared to their competitors, and price is one obvious way to compete.

Comment: There's also supply and demand. Perhaps they know from historical data that at MCO this weekend there'll be a lot more supply than demand and it's still better to rent out a car with low margins than having it sit on the lot.